# How can I set the discrete graphs of these values without computer programs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions, integers, computational-mathematics

How can I set the discrete graphs of these values without computer programs? (online)

I need to create a discrete graph of the following values.Without the computer, is it possible that I can do this?

I tried Wolfram Alpha, but it is impossible to do so because the number of values ​​is so long.

Thank you..

**EXAMPLE**

I would like to set up a graph similar to the graphs of the following distribution functions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> $$\text {Plot 1}\left\{ 9,27,67,118,220,348,486,771,825,1214,1373,1633,2257,1906,2554,2557,2737,3353,2728,3572,2798,3278,3935,3040,3969,2675,3469,3713,2907,3630,2491,3269,2647,2733,3408,2315,3043,1931,2584,2710,2155,2789,1904,2566,2473,2331,3061,2134,2871,1939,2595,3186,2249,3031,1967,2575,2440,2253,2909,1827,2398,1549,1992,2595,1593,2098,1248,1661,1819,1347,1741,991,1320,792,964,1310,710,939,507,694,826,473,651,341,468,264,328,494,253,357,179,263,348,180,273,130,193,133,157,209,100,138,63,91,130,58,79,40,67,58,53,77,40,53,24,32,48,22,35,20,25,28,14,17,11,15,5,8,17,7,8,2,2,4,4,8,2,2,0,1,3,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1\right\}$$
>
> $$\text {Plot 2}\left\{ 10,34,90,176,350,577,871,1436,1657,2534,2966,3764,5358,4882,6698,6791,7702,9604,8231,10947,8918,10913,12958,10509,13828,9786,12794,13566,11358,14039,9970,13110,10714,11362,14112,9696,12748,8299,10977,11669,9297,11941,8009,10755,10446,9502,12403,8392,11276,7651,10182,12325,9126,12174,8067,10627,10042,9292,12137,7975,10516,6945,8760,11373,7282,9587,5943,7862,8529,6461,8474,5139,6852,4337,5341,6935,4055,5350,3019,4024,4776,3023,4058,2251,3039,1851,2247,3039,1720,2289,1249,1742,2273,1290,1830,987,1372,972,978,1372,767,1038,538,722,994,529,710,367,535,509,393,589,316,401,226,297,389,197,290,143,202,226,147,211,103,140,79,101,142,67,106,51,67,75,46,65,32,45,36,42,55,24,34,11,12,25,9,21,8,17,10,9,11,5,14,5,7,6,3,7,4,5,7,6,6,3,2,0,1,2,0,2,2,3,2,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,1,2 \right\}$$
>
> $$\text {Plot 3}\left\{ 11,41,118,251,532,924,1500,2580,3164,5018,6108,8193,12030,11599,16410,16947,20329,25638,23361,31525,26494,33543,39633,33833,44866,33020,43543,45974,41030,50612,37388,49151,40472,44081,54221,38847,51156,33921,44680,48127,38710,48902,33436,44407,43373,39062,50116,34268,45652,30338,40610,47920,36278,48435,32356,42939,41366,37675,49334,33062,43626,29838,37507,48140,31771,42095,26739,35539,37571,29438,38388,24218,32092,21490,26087,33871,20799,27405,16238,21484,25225,16608,22120,12875,17174,10980,13179,17537,10097,13580,7732,10423,13393,7912,10700,6146,8242,6077,6224,8464,4728,6495,3578,4873,6457,3565,4909,2640,3644,3535,2742,3829,2090,2847,1587,2128,2914,1549,2116,1147,1600,1751,1134,1596,838,1190,645,836,1169,600,853,452,668,780,409,581,292,423,278,324,474,242,334,158,234,327,166,234,114,165,110,107,171,84,138,66,86,114,56,78,41,57,70,49,63,26,49,25,36,51,14,22,12,18,23,20,20,6,11,4,10,15,9,10,5,8,11,6,10,6,9,5,8,14,7,14,7,7,5,1,5,1,2,4,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1\right\}$$

Comment: a) What does it mean to *set* a graph? b) What graph(s) are you referring to with these sets (actually lists?) or integers? If these are the vertices, what are the edges?

Comment: If you mean "without programming" by "without computer program", you could use spreadsheet software like MS Excel or LIbreOffice Calc.  Otherwise, whip out a sheet of graph paper.  ;-)

Comment: Would we be correct in thinking that shorter WolframAlpha input, like [Plot 1{9,27,67,118,220,348,486,771}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+1%7B9,27,67,118,220,348,486,771%7D) returns what you want?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen yes you are right.I gave incomplete information. These values ​​are the values ​​of the function, where, $x=1,2,3,4,5,.....$

Comment: @Mark McClure yes you are right. But here, $x=1,2,3...$ discrete values. Not a continous. For example, $x≠1.2$ Actually I need a histogram.

Comment: I need a similar poisson discrete distribution plot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick copy and paste your data to a text file.  Save as .csv file.  Import into LO Calc.  Copy transpose.  Insert/Object/Chart.

Ced

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much..which distribution function in Mathematics is more similar?

Comment: @Beginner, is the "dip" around 40 significant?

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand your question..( english is my second language)

Comment: Can you plotting in diagram? ( For in example, which I gave in question..) Thank you!

Comment: @Beginner,Your data does not produce smooth curves.  A probability distribution is going to be a smooth curve to which you find the parameters that make a best fit to your data.  You can now describe your data using those parameters.  The variation of your data from the best fit is what is of interest.  Is it due to noise?  Is it due to an incorrect probability model?  Is it an attribute of the system you are studying?  Your data looks like a Poisson distribution would be a good fit, but right around x=43 you are getting a variation in all three of your sets.

Comment: I think, if we dividing all values ​​by their number, We can obtain probabilistic distribution, isn't it? Which that total of values will equal to $1$.

Comment: @Beginner, I'm not the best at probability distributions.  This is a different question than knowing how to plot values.  I think you should reframe your question and post it as a new question and you are likely (pun intended) to get a better answer than what I can give.

Comment: I need your Help..@Cedron Dawg :( :(..Can you help?

Comment: @Beginner, I've been expecting an email from you.  I'm not sure what I can do, but let's start there:  cedron at exede dot net.

Comment: Perfect.Please send me an empty sms :  mathlove2018@mail.ru

Comment: I dodn't not understand your Email clearly. please write me a message : mathlove2018@mail.ru